# PHP - getting str from array

Tags: php

I'm using this php code to get all the images from a folder and put  all the results in an array:

```
<?php

$images = [];
$dir    = 'images/*';
$file = glob($dir);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($file); $x++) {
          $images[] = [ $file[$x] => $x];
}

print_r($images);

?>
```

Where i'm getting my results stored in the "$images" array:

```
print_r($images);
Output : /*Array ( [0] => Array ( [images/1.jpg] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [images/2.jpg] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [images/3.jpg] => 2 ) )*/
```

Now, i want to get the first value of the array in a string format, "images/1.jpg" i tried to print it out using its index but it displays the key and the word array in the beginning:

```
print_r($images[0]);
Output : /*Array ( [images/1.jpg] => 0 )*/
```

How to get only this value : "images/1.jpg" ?

Thanks.

Comment: That's it. Do `echo($images[0]);` ...  The command print_r add additional info. The command echo will just output the value.

Comment: @Daniel you can’t just `echo` an array.

Comment: @EdCottrell - Ah... you're of course correct. There is a little more complexity here with being multi-dimensional ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate through collections.

> ```
> foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
>     statement
>
> foreach (array_expression as $value)
>     statement
> ```

In your case this would be

```
foreach (glob($dir) as $filename) {
    print_r($filename);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested array, and the *keys* of the inner array (not the values) contain the image names. So, you need to reference it like this:

```
$names = array_keys($images[0]);
print_r($names[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score -2):

You have to change the `for` loop to tgis:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($file); $x++) { 
{
$images[x] = [$file[$x]];
}
```